# Unable to hot deploy a karaf feature

Tags: apache-karaf, jbossfuse

I am unable to get hot deployment of karaf feature to work in JBoss Fuse. I have the following feature XML descriptor in `deploy` directory, but it never gets picked up by Fuse and it never gets installed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<features name="IssSysIntRepo">
    <feature name="sys-int" install="auto" version="1.0.0">
        <bundle>file:/opt/sys-int.jar</bundle>
        <feature>camel-jackson</feature>
        <feature>camel-restlet</feature>
    </feature>
</features>
```

If I manually add the repository by URL that leads to the file in `deploy` directory by `features:addurl path/feature.xml` and then install the feature by `features:install sys-int` it loads the feature successfully.

Logs on startup do not mention anything about the feature or an error, as I quickly looked over it.

Do you know where might be a problem?

I am using fresh install of jboss-fuse-karaf-full 6.2.0.redhat-099

Comment: Can you try with version 6.2.0.redhat-133? I had similar problems in deploy with older version.

Comment: Is there a direct download link somewhere without needing an account? I need to download the zip to docker image.

Comment: Nope, even with 133 it does not deploy it. It does only manually.